# Is there a way to stop Expired email notification in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I have integration of DocuSign in a .Net application where I'm creating and sending envelopes via DocuSign REST API v2.

I have a requirement to stop expired email notifications for all signers.

However, I failed to find any specific configuration related to my requirement.

I have unchecked the "The sender voids an envelope" notification from the "Email Preferences" setting against API User/User tabs, but DocuSign still sends expired email notifications.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reaching out
My name is Conar and I'm with DocuSign Developer Support.

The DocuSign sender cannot control notifications for the recipient. This is by design. The recipient can opt-out of notifications on their end.

Please confirm if this case can be closed.

Best regards,
Conar | DocuSign Developer Support